# How can I have the footer stay at the bottom of the page while overlapping some of the content on the right with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is the mockup I'm trying to implement (text blurred on purpose):

[image: Mockup]

What I'm struggling with is the footer. The grey triangle in the lower right is HUGE and overlaps the space where the black button and the test element are. The dark bar and the grey triangle are in one image file and I'm using an `img` element for it. The part between the top of the dark bar and the top of the triangle is transparent.

What is a good way to use flexbox and have the left triangle overlap the content, so that when the text overflows on the page and the user needs to scroll, then the footer stays at the bottom but the text gets clipped at the top of the bottom dark grey bar?

I'm also struggling with resizing the page horizontally. What's a good way to make the dark grey bar at the bottom and the black bar at the top be of "variable" length while the triangle at the bottom and the white part on the top stays on the right of the header and footer? For now, it's only one image. I was thinking I'd need to split them so the right parts are their own image, then make a `div` out of the black and dark grey bars, make the bars be background images repeating. And then the right parts are fixed width so only the left part stretches with the window, while filling and clipping the background images as needed.

Finally, the "confettis" under the black circle also need to stretch for as long as the page gets. As it stands, it's all one image in an `img` tag. But when the page is resized vertically, or if more text is present in the middle and overflows, the confettis just stop. How can I make them stretch for as long as the text is? I was thinking here too of splitting the image at the bottom of the circle and have a second `div` right below where the rest of the confettis are set as the background, repeating.

I was stumped by this problem, it seemed straight forward but then I started to actually implement it and realized it was more complicated than I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

It should be fixed to the bottom of the page.

With the rest of the things that are not resizing, try using `width: fixed number like **px**` and same with the height. Also try using the `position` property with css, to position things the way you wan't them to.

Comment: Thanks, that's all that was needed for the footer. Much simpler than what I wanted to do with the background image etc.

Comment: If that was the answer, can you click the check mark please? It would help. Thanks!